# Using STL in iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios, stl

Searching on the net I could not find any tutorials taking one through the steps to using the STL in an iOS app. So for instance, if I wanted to use a Vector in my app's back end worker classes  which don't interact with any Cocoa structures.

If someone could perhaps give me a simple "Hello world" equivalent for this, that would be much appreciated. Or point me to any tutorials that they may have found.

Thanks

Comment: What's the actual question here? What have you tried? Because you should have no problem using the STL from C++ or Objective-C++ code in your app. In fact, if you have ARC on, you can even store Obj-C objects in STL containers and everything will work correctly (e.g. they will be retained/released as necessary).

Comment: As far as actual trials are concerned I could not find any tutorials/explanations merging the two areas (iOS app dev and STL data structure usage) and so with no starting point I could not try anything. Which is why I was asking for either an example or for links, sources where I could get a primer of sorts. If this is not traditionally the format for a question then I do apologize.

Comment: I never used worker classes, but what's wrong with NSMutableArray instead of a vector?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using the NS counterparts instead of the STL structures. I was asking because there are other structures like the hashmap, priority queue, etc which (as far as I know) do not exist out of the box, or in their standard forms, within the NS realm. It seems like a useful tool to have to expand one's iOS toolbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample code. Create a new ios project, set BuildSettings->Apple LLVM Language->Compile Sources As to "Objective-C++".  Open "ViewController.m" and add this line

```
#import "queue"
```

and put this into the viewDidLoad.

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> P;
std::priority_queue<P> queue;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    queue.push(P(rand(), i));
}    
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i, queue.pop())
{
    P p = queue.top();
    printf("%u %u\n",p.first,p.second);
}
```

works for me.

Comment: Thanks! That works. Now my next question is, is there an obj-c++ STL documentation anywhere which lists out the headers and their classes? Or is the general strategy just to import <required_data_structure> and then to code sense around till you get it? Complete newbie to STL so I apologize in advance.