# Loading STL into an Objective-C project and compiling

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, stl

A Stack Overflow post about data structures said you can use STL in Objective-C and iOS development. The link he gave has the link to STL download as http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/

It is nothing but header files and I'm not sure whether I need any other files. But let's say that works. I thought I could just put the files in a folder in my project folder and add them all to the project I have, so far a simple chat client. But would that cause them all to load in my file view? Is there a right way to do this?

Comment: That version of the STL is almost 13 years old! You probably don't want to use that code. Much of the STL has been incorporated into the C++ standard library these days. What specific parts do you want to use? You might not have to do anything special, aside from including the right headers in your C++ code.

Comment: all you need to do is rename the file to *.mm and #include the header

Comment: lets say i just want vector for now what would i do?

Comment: though i want it in objective-c

Comment: if you want it in objective-c, is STL vector necessary?

Comment: i saw that objective-c had few data structures.  array, dictionary and one other i recall. what's the functionality of array? Vector wasn't my final choice kind of want a queue. Actually it may be more sensible to write my own data structure.

Comment: see post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942609/using-stl-in-ios-app/14174493#14174493

Answer (score 4, accepted):

all you need to do is to rename the file to *.mm. this tell the compiler it is Objective-C++ code. you can use both Objective-C object and C++ object at same time.

then if you want to use vector, just `#include <vector>` and use it like in normal C++ code.

Comment: This answer seems to answer my question. I will choose it later want to keep some discussion open still.